# Is the word for 'helper' used to describe Eve in Genesis 2, also used for God helping Israel?

Tags: genesis, word-study

I heard in a sermon podcast I was listening to, this claim:

> *Now the word used for helper when describing Eve is the same word used to describe God in the way he helps Israel*

This being in Genesis 2:18 (NIV):

> The Lord God said, “It is not good for the man to be alone. I will make a helper suitable for him.”

The point being that 'helper' is not a pejorative, but is highly honorable.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key clause in Genesis 2:18 is

> אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ **עֵזֶר** כְּנֶגְדּוֹ
>   *ʾeʿĕśeh-lô **ʿēzer** kᵉnegdô*
>   I will make for him **a helper** fit for him

This noun (עֵזֶר, *ʿēzer*, the same root that the name "Ezra" comes from) appears 21× in the Hebrew Bible.<sup>1</sup>

It is indeed used for Israel's help from the LORD, unambiguously, e.g., in

- Ps 33:20<sub>[esv]</sub> Our soul waits for the LORD; he is our **help** and our shield.
- Ps 121:2<sub>[esv]</sub> My **help** comes from the LORD, who made heaven and earth. (cf. 124:8)

Here's the [Brown-Driver-Briggs entry](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/740/mode/1up) for it:<sup>2</sup>

[image: BDB entry for עזר (n)]

As that entry puts it, *ʿēzer* is not used exclusively of the LORD, but it is "especially" used of the LORD.

So, **it is true** that the same term that Genesis 2:18, 20 uses to refer to the "woman" (אִשָּׁה, *ʾiššâ*, Gen 2:22) made to go with the "man" (אָדָם, *ʾādām*), also refers to the LORD being a "helper" for Israel. Obviously it is not an exclusive relationship (i.e., not an exclusively "theological" term). Thus it would **not be true** to claim that it is, itself, a term of honour -- that comes with context.

---

*Notes*

1. Gen. 2:18, 20; Exod. 18:4; Deut. 33:7, 26, 29; Ps. 20:3; 33:20; 70:6; 89:20; 115:9-11; 121:1-2; 124:8; 146:5; Isa. 30:5; Ezek. 12:14; Dan. 11:34; Hos. 13:9.
2. The little dagger symbol at the beginning of the entry indicates that all occurrences are cited.

Comment: Haha, I was in the middle of editing that typo when you did. Good answer.

Comment: @Daи - ha! I'm sure there are more (sadly!).

Comment: I'm having a hard time not seeing עֵזֶר as inherently a "term of honour" **relatively** speaking _from the perspective of the one being helped_ (sarcastic use being an exception). If one considers oneself _aided_, there is a form of honor given simply in acknowledging that. To not feel helped has a dishonor associated with it (e.g. Isa 30:5). Now **absolutely** speaking, thieves or murderers helping each other is not honorable, because the act is not honorable (e.g. Ezek 12:14); but they would still relatively hold their helpers in some form of honor by acknowledging them as helping. Thoughts?

Comment: @ScottS - I can see the line you're taking, but that's not how I understand semantics to work. "**Relatively** inherent" is a way of saying it depends on context, no? And your "relative/absotlute" distinction is just another way of saying there are different contexts. The quality of "honour" isn't conveyed by *ʿēzer*, but by context (cf. Is 30:5; Ezk 12:14; Dn 11:34). Contrast, e.g. *hādār*, which **does** bear this nuance. For more, see D. Geeraerts, *[Theories of Lexical Semantics](http://www.amazon.com/dp/019870030X/)*; Cruse, *[Meaning in Language](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0199559465/)*.

Comment: "Depends on context"? No. Take Ezek 12:14. The word "help" can be viewed both relatively & absolutely _from that context_. Relatively, those helping the prince are going to be viewed _by the prince_ with honor (else they were not helpful), while absolutely, God views the helpers with dishonor (because He is against their rebellion, v.9). So _regardless of context_, the one _being_ "helped" looks on that help positively, never pejoratively. But from an outside view of the morality of the help offered, it may or may not yield a positive. So by definition, help is positive _to the one so helped_.

Comment: To be clear, I am not arguing direct "meaning" (help means _help_, not honor, like _hādār_), but the connotation of the word "help." This seems to be the OP's question for Gen 2:18. God's perspective is that Eve will be a helper. So both absolutely (from God's eyes) and relatively (how she would be perceived from Adam's eyes, pre-sin), it was purely an honorable state, without question not pejorative. Context can determine if the relative/absolute match up as positive or not, but the term would _always_ seem to have a _relative_ connotation of honor by definition. Do you see issues with that?

Comment: @Ruminator what I'm saying is that by merely labeling someone as a _helper_, a person is by default/definition showing them the "honor" of _recognizing_ they helped (or will help). If someone had helped, but no one ever recognized them by even labeling them as a _helper_, then yes, no recognition would have come. The  OP stated "The point being that 'helper' is not a pejorative, but is highly honorable," of which I would say the term is not necessarily "highly" honorable, but still honorable at some level as opposed to pejorative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're focus in this verse is misplaced.  Genesis 2:18 quotes G-d as saying that he will make make man a "helper corresponding to him" (Art Scroll translation) but the Hebrew says "ezer k'negdo" which literally means a "helper against him.". The Babylonian Talmud's commentary on this verse (Yevamot 63a), and Rashi's commentary,  explain that the Torah is saying that she will be a helper when he is worthy, and that she will be an adversary when he. Is not worthy.  It is the wife's obliation to support her husband when he seeks to do what is right and oppose him when his evil inclination leads him instead.  At those times she helps him most by opposing him.   That G-d does the same is obvious, but Judaism understands that  women are inherrently more spiritual than men and therefore are first line of defense before our mistakes equire Divine. Intervention.

Comment: Can you please cite the sources you mention so we can see what is actually being said rather than your interpretation? And can you show from a lexicon or commentary what "ezer k'negdo" means in the Art Scroll and in the Hebrew? It isn't that I think you are lying it is that this site requires primary sources so we don't play the "telephone game" where the original message gets distorted by interpretation. Thanks.

Comment: Also, can you please show some evidence that "Judaism understands that women are inherrently more spiritual than men" and the wife's alleged role as "opponent" if she disagrees with her man? Thanks.